# Turpentine Module crash to clear Varnish ESI cache for client

Tags: varnish, turpentine

My bug is the same of tile in this post.
The log in `/magento/var/log/system.log` is:

```
2015-09-24T22:59:28+00:00 WARN (4): TURPENTINE: Failed to clear Varnish ESI cache for client: 7iil0pit3svj0oa30lmk5rvtf7
2015-09-24T23:01:45+00:00 WARN (4): TURPENTINE: Error in Varnish action result for server [127.0.0.1:6082]: Got unexpected response code from Varnish: 107
yufhrmorpdgfjlzuyuwnoxchxkgcdvjb

Authentication required.

2015-09-24T23:01:45+00:00 WARN (4): TURPENTINE: Failed to clear Varnish ESI cache for client: 7iil0pit3svj0oa30lmk5rvtf7
```

And in admin magento when i change options in `VARNISH options` in turpentine says the same error:
[image]

What is this, and how i can solve? thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Magento, and what version of Turpentine and Varnish are you using? May help get you a better/faster answer.

Answer (score 0):

This error generally means you're using a version of Varnish that Turpentine doesn't know how to talk to. In the past, this usually mean Varnish 4 - although we've added Varnish 4 support now.

If you can, update Turpentine to the current version and see if the problem persists. If it does, try setting the specific version of Varnish in the Magento back-end configuration, rather than relying on automatic detection.